# How to get the result of a query which has several lines as a result in one single line separated by one separator?

Tags: sql-server

I need to get the value from one query as a single row, separated by one separator, chosen but me, but it's a little tricky.

So, I have:

```
select employer from employers
```

I will return:

```
(line1)    Anne
(line2)    Sue
(line3)    Villy
(line4)    John
(nth line) Marry
```

I need to have the result as this:

```
'Anne','Sue','Villy','John','Marry'
```

Or at least:

```
 Anne^Sue^Villy^John^Marry
```

Any hints?
Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
declare @s varchar(max) = ''

select @s = case 
    when @s <> '' then  
        @s + ',''' + employer + ''''
    else 
        @s + '''' + employer + '''' end 
from employers

select @s
```

Comment: Thanks a million. Saved me from cursors! It worked like a charm. Have a great day!

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT  ', ' + Employer AS [text()]
FROM Employers
FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1,'')
```